# Creating Multiple pages with different text to print with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, printing

So I am creating a basic asp.bet website. Which in end, generates a receipt to print like this-

[image: Receipt Image]

So I am printing this receipt with simple **javascript** code.
The javascript code goes like-

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function printData() {
                if (confirm("Data Saved!\nDo you want to take a Print?")) {
                    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("<%=divAll.ClientID %>");
                    newWin = window.open("");
                    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
                    newWin.document.close();
                    newWin.focus();
                    newWin.print();
                    newWin.close();
                }
            }
    </script>
```

(Above receipt is coded in tables and "divAll" is the main division which has all the tables. And the text **CONSIGNEE COPY** is a simple text in a table division.) 
and the code for print button goes like-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print Consignment" OnClientClick="printData();"/>
```

What I want to do is to take 4 copies of the receipt with different text in place of CONSIGNEE COPY- 
 
1- CONSIGNEE COPY  
2- DRIVER COPY  
3- TAX COPY  
4- OFFICE COPY

So now my question is, can I do that with javascript? 
The **printData()** function of javascript is already opening a new window. Can I append a new page in **newWin** with same receipt but with different text(in place of CONSIGNEE COPY). So that finally the **newWin** has 4 pages with different text on each page. Is that possible? How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the Help. :)

**#Edit:** 
OK, so after some searching I managed to add my receipt two times in print preview.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function printData() {
                if (confirm("Data Saved!\nDo you want to take a Print?")) {
                    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("<%=divAll.ClientID %>");                    
                    newWin = window.open("");
                    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = divToPrint.innerHTML;
                    div.setAttribute("style", "font-family:Arial !important;");
                    div.setAttribute("align", "center");
                    newWin.document.body.appendChild(div);
                    newWin.document.close();
                    newWin.focus();
                    newWin.print();
                    newWin.close();
                }
            }
    </script>
```

by above method I can add 4 pages too, but how can I change the **CONSIGNEE COPY** value each time? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

just change one line, and iterate for other remaining copies

```
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML.replace("CONSIGNEE COPY", "DRIVER COPY"));
```